# cURL request in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, axios, child-process

Can somebody help me figure out how to convert the following request:

```
curl -F media=@image.jpg <url>
```

to preferably an axios request.

Comment: It's a  `multipart/form-data` encoded POST request including an image, just use axios.post() and add the headers and the image as a FormData object

Comment: Can you let me know what should be the image in the FormData object because I have tried a few things and they did not work. Also I set the headers as { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } which I assume is the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)

Here is an example code:

```
const childProcess = require('child_process');
[...]

const output = childProcess
    //filePath is "image.jpg"; url is the link where the image will be uploaded
    .execSync(`curl -F media=@${filePath} "${url}"`)
    .toString('utf8');

const response = JSON.parse(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
axios.put(url, imageFile, {
headers: {
'Content-Type': imageFile.type
});
  .then(function(response) {
   //Handle success.
});
  .catch(function (error) {
   //Handle errors.
});
```

Comment: "Something like this", probably, but this will not send an image

Comment: No, I want to upload the image not download it

Comment: I should probably commented this instead of posting an answer but i don't have 50 reputation, so i thought maybe he can figure it out from here :)